# Does loading json object inside text input slow down page performance

Tags: json, ajax, performance

I have  a page that i load up product information using ajax when click on the product, but on mobile it a kind of slow to retrieve all the information from sever as it will delays opening product preview box. So i just came up with an idea to create a hidden input and pass the product related information in the hidden input then read it from there when product is clicked. My question now is about performance is this a good practice or wile creating the hidden input will slow down the page performance too?

```
<div class="item openItem" data-id="100">
    <span>car</span>
    <input type="hidden" id="object-100" value='{"name":"car", "id": 100, ......}'/>
</div>

<div class="item openItem" data-id="101">
    <span>bird</span>
    <input type="hidden" id="object-101" value='{"name":"bird", "id": 102, ......}'/>
</div>

<div class="item openItem" data-id="103">
    <span>dog</span>
    <input type="hidden" id="object-103" value='{"name":"car", "id": 103, ......}'/>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

I think the best way to solve this is to

- yes, load the info with the page
- no, do not load it as a hidden input field

My aproach would be to but a `<script>` tag at the **very end** of the HTML, that contains something like

```
var itemData={
  "100": {"name":"car", "id": 100, ......},
  "101": {"name":"bird", "id": 102, ......},
  "109": {"name":"car", "id": 103, ......}
};
```

and then reference the global variable `itemData` instead of the input fields.

The rationale behind this is:

- every modern HTML rendering engine will start to render the page, even if a `<script>` tag at the end has not finished loading, but it will not start rendering 'dog' before 'bird' has finished loading
- A user loading the page will need a few moments before interacting with it - time enough to load the data
- Loading data directly into a variable takes less processing power than fetching them from a hidden input **at the time of interaction**

Answer (score 0):

The hidden inputs won't slow down your app, and if it does, the amount of slow down will be tiny. They are hidden and so aren't rendered to the document (which could be a problem if you had hundreds of them).

However, this isn't the best way to do it and I would go back to using ajax to load in  the product information. There are a couple of reasons for this.

- Ajax is asynchronous so the rest of the information on the page can load and you could have loading spinners where the product information would be. Then you can pop the product information in once you get it from the server.
- Imagine if you changed a product in your database. If you were using ajax to get the information from your server, everything would work fine. It would be updated in your app automatically. But, if you have the information in the hidden inputs, you will need to update that in the app and then release an update for your app each time you want to change products.

Comment: Your second point doesn't stand: the product information is updated each time the "page" is loaded. Actually, in such a situation, using AJAX would confuse the user since the information displayed in the preview would differ. Nevermind, I though it was a detail page, instead it seems it's an inventory page. In this case it's better to reload the info.

Answer (score 0):

Personally I think you have opted for the best solution.
In this case, it would be best to load all the products with their respective details that you will store in HTML attributes (just like containers) by preceding the name of the attribute by `data-`.
You can easily retrieve them from your javascript code once the product is chosen to be viewed.
The advantage of this method is that you will make a server request once, which corresponds to the time of recovery of all products, and you will no longer need to make other requests for just viewing the product. But if product data changes instantly it can be a disadvantage and I think that is not the case for your appication.
If you want to gain performance, adopt this method that you used, I think it's the best.
I hope this answer will be useful to you.